# Не могу добавить каталог в PATH

Tags: linux, bash

Мой .bashrc выглядит так:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH="$PATH:/home/project_manager/kafka/bin"

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
```

Что с ним не так? Путь точно правильный.

Comment: в чем выражается "не так"?

Comment: @Эникейщик ну раз я не могу написать kafka-topislcs.sh, то значит, что я неправильно описал каталог в PATH. Что-то с ним не так.

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=...
```

Если PATH нужна не в консоли, а в программе, то лучше положить это выражение в `~/.profile` И полностью разлогиниться желательно.

Comment: exec $SHELL достаточно

Comment: Нужна в терминале.

Comment: тогда только экспорта не хватает

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что сервер был под рутом, и необходимо было редактировать .bashrc в каталоге ./root/